# Best way to REPLACE with MySQL for usernames

Tags: php, mysql, replace

I'm developing a site in PHP and it's setup with its own status and wall system right now (similar to twitter and facebook, respectively).  I'm trying to make it so a user can change his username later on and any statuses or wall posts that mention the user (as in "@woo hi!") will be replaced with the new username.

I've tried using the REPLACE query in MySQL, but obviously I can't just replace 'username' with 'newusername', because if someone with the username of @w changed their username to @f, then someone else's account with the username @woo will become @foo.  Get my drift?

I think my option is to basically create my own format to save the statuses/wall posts in that replace the username @woo with the |woo| (or anything that denotes an ending of the username), but I was curious if someone else had a different idea on the matter, or if someone knew about making the REPLACE query do this for me (like a way to make it scan as whole words, so that way @w != @woo.  I'd love to hear what you think.

EDIT:

I figured out what I'm gonna do and am updating this for anyone else's future reference. I decided to replace all @usernames in statuses/wall posts with #@usernames# and save them like that in the DB. So now I can use a simple REPLACE query with MySQL to replace all the username mentions in statuses/wall posts, and won't have ambiguity problems (@w turns into #@w# in my database, which means that changing the username @w (#@w#) to @f (#@f#) won't change #@woo# to #@foo#.  Of course when displaying the usernames in posts now, I have to run the content through an "unformat" function with strips the # at the start and end, but that's not too bad.

Comment: there are only twitter and facebook, don't waste time :)

Comment: What if MZ had given up because of MySpace? :p

Comment: yes123, I prefer answers that progress my knowledge on the question at hand please.  And as for there only being twitter and facebook, there also used to be "only myspace".

Answer (score 1):

You could design your database to store additional data about each status/posts, for example, a list of all user ids for users mentioned in the post.  Then, it would be easy to execute a targeted search and replace by:

- Locating all posts that mention a user changing their name **by joining on their id**
- Replacing `$oldname` with `$newname` in only those posts

You may still have a small margin of ambiguity (multiple mentions in a single post), but you should be able to write a regular expression that identifies `$oldname` **and not a substring** of `$oldname`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I like the idea too.  I'll definitely be considering that idea.